# Which other tools to use if PING fails

Tags: linux-networking, ping, arp

I have checked this [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/18506/what-to-check-if-pinging-doesnt-work) and I understand the use of traceroute, but I do not understand why I should use ARP if PING fails.

Details: I use Linux machine to ping the servers out of which some servers are available in the LAN and some are available in the WAN. Also, I would appreciate if someone can provide me the usage and possible errors with ARP.

Comment: Because sometimes firewalls block ping, but if they block arp, the computer won't work at all?

Comment: @Zoredache So if arp provides successful result, does that mean the server is up ?

Comment: Only on a LAN. Otherwise it's the gateway/router responding to the ARP request.

Comment: @roaima can you please elaborate more?

Comment: ARP is a LAN protocol. To reach systems via a gateway it has to be the gateway that responds to an ARP request.